# Rebase-merge another branch into the current one

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to rebase another branch onto the current one without moving the other branch or switching to it? This is the feature that github calls "rebase and merge" in pull requests.

So I want to have the same result as if running these commands (starting on `master`):

```
git checkout -b tmp feature
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

But it is important to me that I don't actually switch to the other branch. `feature` might be many commits behind master and I am working on a huge c++ codebase. I don't want a full rebuild to merge a branch that only touched two files.

I tried `git cherry-pick HEAD^ feature`, but that complains if commits from `feature` where cherry-picked to master before. Also, I would prefer to have the option of an interactive rebase, so I can change a commit message or leave out a commit in this step.

I also found `git merge feature --strategy=ours && git rebase HEAD^`. But creating that useless merge seems strange and if I abort the rebase, I now have to remember to delete the merge from my master.

In case I am missing something very basic and should approach this completely differently: My context is that I'm using git-svn to work against a svn repository. I have a worktree with a current build of trunk. I want to get my feature-branch commits, make sure the new state builds, maybe polish some commits and push the changes to the svn repo.

Comment: you can create another clone "second" of the "real" repo, switch branches in "second" there, do the rebase in "second" and then pull the branch brack into your "real" repo (after possibly dropping the branch there, to avoid conflicts). probably not the nicest approach, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a small script to solve my issue. Save this as `git-rmerge` somewhere in your path and now you can run `git rmerge my_feature` while on `master` to interactive-rebase `my_feature` into to the master branch.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/rmerge

target=$(git rev-parse $1)

env GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="cp \$1 $tmpfile && false" git rebase --quiet -i HEAD $target 2>/dev/null
exec env GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="mv $tmpfile \$1 && vim \$1" git rebase -i HEAD
```

Note that this script assumes you use `vim` as your editor. If that is not the case, change the call to `vim` in the last line.

It works like this: It asks git for an interactive rebase of `my_feature` onto HEAD. This causes git to open the editor with the rebase steps it would perform (but git doesn't actually check anything out yet). We use the `EDITOR` env var to redirect these rebase steps into `$tmpfile` instead of opening an editor. We then tell git to not even start the rebase by returning non-zero from our editor (by running `false`).

We now start a second interactive rebase, rebasing HEAD onto itself. This would open the editor with an empty list of rebase steps. We once again use the `EDITOR` env var to pre-load the steps stored in `$tmpfile` before opening the actual editor. Now we can make changes to these rebase steps if desired or just exit the editor to run the rebase normally.

All of this causes git to do the rebase steps directly against the currently checked-out branch without modifying the other branch.